# Understanding Style and Template in XAML/WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I will start with the code. Here is the simple button:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Height="20" Width="100" 
            Background="Brown" 
            BorderBrush="Blue" 
            Foreground="Aqua">Test button</Button>
</Grid>
```

I set Background, BorderBrush and Foreground **in Button control**.

Below I have a code, exactly the same result, but with defining style and template:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="foo"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Brown"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Aqua"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Height="20" Width="100">
        Test button
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Here is what confuses me:

1. I declare style and template, then I declare `ControlTemplate`, then inside `ControlTemplate` I declare `Border` and then... `Background` inside `Border` tag. WHY? It's a background of button's content - it has nothing to do with border. That doesn't make sense for me.
2. What's even more weird, now every poperty, that I want to set for Button (like background for example) I have to set for Button's border. Even button's content. Why `ContentPresenter` must be inside `Border`?

Btw. if I ditch border and just want content then, this is correct:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentPresenter>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

So, my question would be: Why when declaring template I have to set `Background` of the button inside button's `Border`?

This example with `Button` it's just an example. More general answer/explanation would be great!

Answer (score 2):

When you override the template of a `Control` like `Button` you essentially control the whole look and feel of that `Control`. You are replacing the visual tree of that `Control`.

So when you put a `Button` in your application, it will contain the subtree that is found in its `ControlTemplate`.

This can be observed in Visual Studio 2015's Live Visual Tree pane or in Snoop:

[image: Visual Tree of default Button]

`Button` is a `ContentControl`, that means that its `ContentPropertyAttribute` is set to `"Content"`. A `ContentPresenter` in a `ContentControl`'s `ControlTemplate` will pick up whatever you've put inside the `ContentControl`'s `Content` property (you don't even need the `TemplateBinding` for `ContentPresenter`'s `Content` in your case). If you use a simple string `Content` like `<Button Content="Whatever" />` it will be converted to `<TextBlock Text="Whatever" />`, hence the TextBlock in the visual tree in the picture.

In the example you provided the `Border` element is used to let the user be able to set a Background to the `Button`. Because `ContentPresenter` doesn't have a `Background` property you have to wrap it in a `Border` element and set the `Background` on the `Border`.

I think the name `Border` might be confusing, it's not always strictly used for rendering borders (although in this case, it is used for that and for the `Background` as well).

I hope this kinda makes sense, if you have further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand this: "(you don't even need the TemplateBinding for ContentPresenter's Content in your case). If you use a simple string Content like <Button Content="Whatever" /> it will be converted to <TextBlock Text="Whatever" />, hence the TextBlock in the visual tree in the picture." If I remove this: `<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentPresenter>` there will be no content at all. If I change to `<ContentPresenter Content="Foo"></ContentPresenter>` it will be "Foo" always.

Comment: I meant if you only have `<ContentPresenter />` without the `Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"` part, it would still display whatever you put in the `Content` property of your `Button`.

Comment: By the other thing I meant that when you clearly set the `Content` to a string like this: `<Button Content="Something" />`. That will be rendered as a `<TextBlock Text="Something" />`. So it's basically equivalent to `<Button><TextBlock Text="Something" /></Button>`.